# How can I merge changes from an upstream branch to my fork's branch

Tags: git, merge, git-fetch

I want to pull changes from an upstream repo's branch.
I have set the upstream repo using:

```
git remote add upstream http://URL-of-master-repo.git
```

and then I tried to pull the changes using

```
git checkout my-local-branch
git fetch upstream remote-branch
git merge upstream/remote-branch
```

but the files still didn't appear on my disk, but I get a conflict:

```
Auto-merging minimal-build-config.cmake
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in minimal-build-config.cmake
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How do I properly resolve the conflict to be able to fetch the files from the upstream branch?

Comment: If you are getting a merge conflict, then you should resolve it and commit, before trying to assess whether or not that merge were successful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I resolved the conflict & committed the changes but still did not get the files in question, I redid the `git merge upstream/remote-branch` but only got `Already up-to-date`

Comment: Changes/content you might expect to be there can sometimes be removed during a Git merge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it was a couple new files added in the upstream branch... i don't see no reason why they should be removed during a merge

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A good practice is to have this structure, which looks like you do, but is good to explain for clarification purposes:

```
origin  https://github.com/your-username/forked-repository.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/your-username/forked-repository.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/original-owner-username/original-repository.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/original-owner-username/original-repository.git (push)
```

So `origin` is your fork and `upstream` the original repository.
Then use

```
git fetch upstream
```

And you will get this output

```
From https://github.com/original-owner-username/original-repository
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
```

where you have now a branch called `upstream/master` which tracks the original repo.

Then checkout to your local fork branch and merge

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

If you have conflicts (as it seems you do) fix them and commit the changes.

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pull-request-on-github)

Comment: I resolved the conflict & committed the changes but still did not get the files in question, I redid the `git merge upstream/remote-branch` but only got `Already up-to-date`

Comment: do a `git fetch` and `git status` on the `upstream/master` branch and see what you get.

Comment: I am sort of facing the same issue but dont see `upstream/master` branch being presented in the output as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

//fetch from upstream
git fetch upstream
git checkout main
git merge upstream/main
git push origin main

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).